# Is it true that for any square matrix $A$, if $A^4=\text{Id}$ then $A^2=-\text{Id}$ or $A^2=\text{Id}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have tried some $A^2$ is not $-\text{Id}$ or $\text{Id}$ like $\pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & -1}$, but I cannot find the corresponding matrix of $A$ in these cases.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, the shear $[1,1;0,1]$ is a counter example.

Comment: If A is symmetry, $A^2 = I$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Permutation matrix to the rescue! We take the permutation $1 \mapsto 2 \mapsto 3 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 1$ and set entry $$a_{ij} = \begin{cases}1, &i\mapsto j\ \\ 0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ to get the matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}.$$

You can verify on [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=[[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0]]%5E2).

Comment: Nice thing, yours also works in char $2$.

Comment: Thanks! I figured if we were all showing off, I'd join in the fun -- we've got complex numbers, rotations, permutations, and ... Jyrki the mad scientist doing something beyond me!

Answer (score 9):

If you want a counterexample formed by a real matrix, then you can check that
with
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
0&1&0&0\\
-1&0&0&0\\
0&0&-1&0\\
0&0&0&-1\end{array}\right)
$$
you get $A^4=I_4$. The matrix $A^2$ has two non-zero $2\times2$ blocks along the diagonal. The other block is $I_2$, the other $-I_2$, so $A^2\neq\pm I_4$.

Answer (score 7):

This in general is false because if
$$
A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}i&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)
$$
where $i$ is the square root of $-1$,
then
$A^4=I$, but
$$
A^2 = \left(\begin{array}{cc}-1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)
$$
this works because $i$ is one of the $4$ fourth roots of $1$, but it is not a square roots of $1$.

Comment: The answer is off mark.

Comment: @runaround I don't understand what do you mean with "off mark".

Comment: Within Linear Algebra, all matrices are considered real. Complex numbers uses only when eigenvalues are used.

Comment: For non-symmetric matrix, Eric's comment is correct.

Comment: @runaround When I studied (and taught) linear algebra at the university the matrices were considered  over $\Bbb C$ if not specificed otherwise.

Comment: @runaround: That is a very limited view of linear algebra.

Comment: @runaround this is the best trolling comment I have seen in ages.

Comment: I think this is worth keeping. It was the first correct answer, so I voted to undelete. As it happens, my vote is instantly binding :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen We all know how you relish your unilateral powers :P

Answer (score 7):

Like  @Giovanni Resta: 's answer 
$$
A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: This is the matrix of the rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ around the $z$ axis by angle $\pi/2$